# Is there a fast way to use Active Model Serializer in case of getting associations data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, activemodel

I have a Model say Question

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

and in its serialiser

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :tags
end
```

Now if I try to get Question data say `Question.all`, it tries to get tags of each question one by one which is too many db hits. Whereas such data can be queried in one DB call.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Got it. Thank You!

Comment: It sounds like you found your answer in the link @max shared. Would you mind answering your own question with what you did to solve your problem. It will be helpful for other people with a similar question.